# Remove LegendText and their small rectangles from Barchart

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I added this code

```
 DataRenderer.setLegendTextSize(0);
```

to remove the LegendText but I want to remove the small rectangles which appears in the following image

[image]

How can I do that ?

and what is the name legend means in this context ?

Comment: also How can I put the numbers in the center of the columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
renderer.setShowLegend(false);
```

where `renderer` is `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` .

For alligning values on bar

```
renderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
```

where `renderer` is `XYSeriesRenderer`

Comment: renderer.setShowLegend(false); works but renderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER); didn't work